# "Beard comes late to our family males." is the sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

Today, one of my school friends ended up saying:

> **Beard comes late to our family males.**

Is the sentence grammatical? If not, then help me correct.

I'm not a native speaker.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is using 'beard' as an uncountable noun, where it would usually be considered countable. Someone has 'a beard' not 'beard'.

A more natural way to say it would be

> Facial hair comes late to our family's males.

(Note also possessive on 'family').

Like so often, though, while it sounds a bit odd, if you said it to a native English speaker, they probably wouldn't think anything of it, and would know exactly what you mean.

Comment: You could also modify it so that it *is* countable: *Beards come late to our family's males.* (Or *to males in our family*.)